# SSIS to SQL DateTime data type conversion failing

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am a beginner with MS SQL server 2014. Need some advise with data type conversion from SSIS to SQL server.

I am working with DATE TIME field, an example value : '01272016122044123' which is in format 'MMDDYYYYHHMMSSsss'

From SSIS I have used data type "database timestamp with precision [DT_DBTIMESTAMP2]" and in SQL Server I have used data type "DateTime2(7)".

When I am trying to import the data from SSIS it gives me error "An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Invalid date format".

The column status returned was: "Conversion failed because the data value overflowed the specified type.".

Need to know where exactly i go wrong ?

Thanks
Syed Ayaz Mahmud

Comment: What's that last three `sss`

Comment: last 3 digits are millisec counts

Comment: The way that the date is formated right now I think SQL thinks it is an INteger and there isn't a date format that fits that number. If you put it into excel and select a date format I am gonna guess it won't work either. Check out this website it will help https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186724.aspx. You may need to get a little creative with SQL to format the number the right way.

Comment: Hi Palmer, you are right, even when i put that to excel sheet and format it as date/time (tried all sorts) none works. Later on, I have tried to take it as INT and then import to SQL (it works fine). The problem is now I have to use SUBSTRING to re-decorate the numbers. Let me know if you have any other alternatives in your mind. Thanks.

Comment: If you can use it SUBSTRING after insert, just use it before.... and insert correct date time format: ` 
YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss[.nnn]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SSIS is super fussy about converting a string to datetime.  I would do a script task in a dataflow instead:

1. Select the value from the database as a string
2. Add a script component transformation
3. Create a column in the output buffer that is "database timestamp with precision [DT_DBTIMESTAMP2]," making sure that you adjust the scale to 3
4. Use the following in the script:

   ```
   using System.Globalization;

   public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
   {
       CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
       Row.newDate = DateTime.ParseExact(Row.MyDate, "MMddyyyyhhmmssfff", provider);
   }
   ```